# How to prove one-one and onto?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a group of odd order. Show that the function $\phi:G \to G $ given by $\phi(g)=g^2$ is one-one and onto.

To prove one-one, I did 
$\phi(g_1)=\phi(g_2)$ implies $g_1^2=g_2^2$. Somehow I got $g_2^{-1} g_1=g_2g_1^{-1}$. I got stuck here. How to conclude from here? Can anyone give a hint? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pick $x\in G$, since the order of $G$ is odd then the order of $x$ is odd also say $2p+1$.

We have $x^{2p+1}=e$ so $x^{2p+2}=x=(x^{p+1})^2=\phi(x^{p+1})$, so $\phi$  is surjective and by reason of cardinality $\phi$ is bijective.